# How to get position of mouse intersection with model in cesium

Tags: cesiumjs

I'm trying to get the mouse intersection position with models in Cesium

I want to use PoTree measurements on cesium entities also. I've used the Potree Cesium example.

But in that example I saw that cesium and Potree are on two different canvas layers.

```
var pointcloudPoint = scope.getMousePointCloudIntersection();
var modelPoint = viewer.getMouseModelIntersection(scope.mouse);
var nearestPoint = viewer.getModelPointcloudNearestPoint(pointcloudPoint, modelPoint);
var measurmentPoint = getHoveredElement();

if (nearestPoint == null) {
    if (
        measurmentPoint != false
        && viewer.measuringTool.activeMeasurement != null
    ) {
        var point = measurmentPoint.object;
    }
} else {

    var point = nearestPoint;
}
```

Here is how I get different mouse intersection positions

```
if (scope.state == scope.STATE.INSERT && scope.activeMeasurement) {
    var pointcloudPoint = scope.getMousePointCloudIntersection();
    var modelPoint = viewer.getMouseModelIntersection(scope.mouse);
    var nearestPoint = viewer.getModelPointcloudNearestPoint(pointcloudPoint, modelPoint);
    var measurmentPoint = getHoveredElement();

    if (nearestPoint == null) {
        if (
            measurmentPoint != false
            && viewer.measuringTool.activeMeasurement != null
        ) {
            var point = measurmentPoint.object;
        }
    } else {
        var point = nearestPoint;
    }

    if (point) {
        var position = point.position;
        var lastIndex = scope.activeMeasurement.points.length - 1;
        scope.activeMeasurement.setMarker(lastIndex, point);
    }
}
```

Comment: Try loading the [Picking Demo](https://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Build/Apps/Sandcastle/?src=Picking.html) and click the last button on the top row, `Pick position`.  A model of a white truck will appear, try hovering the mouse over positions on this model.  Cesium will show the intersection of the mouse and the model.